# How can we add condition for Date Comparison in AWK

Tags: python, awk, hdfs, date-comparison

I am giving below command to

```
hdfs dfs -ls "+hdfsdir" | awk '{$6 == '2022-03-07' ; {print $8}'
```

$6 contains date in format 2022-03-07.

But when I am executing this query it is giving results for all other dates as well.

Am I doing anything wrong, or is there any other way for passing date in awk?

Comment: Can you check the code you ahve posted? The parantheses seem to be unmatched. Why do you ahve a `;` after the equality check?

Comment: Use double-quotes inside the single-quoted string. Remove the semi-colon

Comment: Sorry I missed parentheses at last here. I have to print values in column $8 after checking equality condition for column $6, that's why added a ; in middle. Is there any other way for passing multiple queries in awk? I have to check for a particular date in column 6 and print values of column 8 for that date only

Comment: @Thor:  After giving double quotes getting syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You can use double quotes to match the date, remove the opening curly and remove `;` or else it will just print field nr 8 as a separate statement.

```
awk '$6 == "2022-03-07" {print $8}'
```

Comment: It is saying invalid syntax after giving double quotes for date

Comment: Did you write it like [in this example](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19ByVDBSMFYwUTBVMHIwMhI18BY18BcSUEpEYjTMlNzUiyUFGoUEsuzFdRVzBRsbRWUkJVVFxRl5pUoqFjUqv//DwA)?

Comment: Yes written exactly like this

Comment: If date is in format 3/7/2022..then also we will give same command?

Comment: @AnshumanMadhav Then you could write it as `awk '$6 == "2022-03-07" || $6 == "2022/03/07" {print $8}'`

Comment: Don't know why it is saying invalid syntax for double quotes. Is there any other way for date comparison?

Comment: @AnshumanMadhav Perhaps you can use it like this `awk -v d1="2022-03-07" -v d2="2022/03/07" '$6 == d1 || $6 == d2 {print $8}'`

Comment: Same response...showing invalid syntax for d1 

Comment: @AnshumanMadhav What is the awk version that you are using?

Comment: awk -W version : GNU Awk 4.0.2

Comment: @AnshumanMadhav: In an MS Windows terminal? Because it has wierd quoting policies, you have to escape the double-quotes, i.e. use `\"`

Comment: @AnshumanMadhav don't ignore the error and look for workarounds or whatever you're doing that;s causing the current error will lead to other errors with other scripts and you might not be lucky enough for it to be a syntax error next time and it's something that happens quietly when running with real data producing incorrect output.

Comment: @Thor: I m executing it in Putty.  What will be the syntax to escape double quotes for that?

Comment: @AnshumanMadhav: putty is a terminal emulator, it has nothing to do with the interpretation of what you type in.

Comment: Hi All, I give the below command and it was able to fetch expected result:  awk '$6 == " ' " 2022-03-07 " ' " {print $8} '. This approach is correct? If we now want to pass the date through a  variable how will we do it?